# Cube texturing in opengl3

Tags: java, opengl, textures, texture-mapping, opengl-3

Just doing my computer graphics assignment - put texture (600x400 bitmap with different numbers) on a cube to form a proper dice. I managed to do it using "classical" texture mapping: creating verices and adding corresponding texture coordinates to it:

```
int arrayindex = 0;
float xpos = 0.0f;
float xposEnd = 0.32f;
float ypos = 0.0f;
float yposEnd = 0.49f;
int count = 0;
void quad( int a, int b, int c, int d ) {
    colors[arrayindex] = vertex_colors[a];
    points[arrayindex] = vertices[a];
    tex_coord[arrayindex] = new Point2(xpos, ypos);
    arrayindex++;
    colors[arrayindex] = vertex_colors[b];
    points[arrayindex] = vertices[b];
    tex_coord[arrayindex] = new Point2(xpos, yposEnd);
    arrayindex++;
    colors[arrayindex] = vertex_colors[c];
    points[arrayindex] = vertices[c];
    tex_coord[arrayindex] = new Point2(xposEnd, yposEnd);
    arrayindex++;
    colors[arrayindex] = vertex_colors[a];
    points[arrayindex] = vertices[a];
    tex_coord[arrayindex] = new Point2(xpos, ypos);
    arrayindex++;
    colors[arrayindex] = vertex_colors[c];
    points[arrayindex] = vertices[c];
    tex_coord[arrayindex] = new Point2(xposEnd, yposEnd);
    arrayindex++;
    colors[arrayindex] = vertex_colors[d];
    points[arrayindex] = vertices[d]; 
    tex_coord[arrayindex] = new Point2(xposEnd, ypos);
    arrayindex++;
    xpos = xpos + 0.34f;
    xposEnd = xpos + 0.32f;
    count++;
    if (count == 3) {
        xpos = 0.0f;
        xposEnd = 0.33f;
        ypos = 0.51f;
        yposEnd = 1.0f;
    }
}

void colorcube() {
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );

    pointsBuf = VectorMath.toBuffer(points);
    colorsBuf = VectorMath.toBuffer(colors);
    texcoord = VectorMath.toBuffer(tex_coord);
}
```

Passing all this stuff to shaders and just putting it up together.

But reviewing the slides i noticed this method is supposed to be "pre opengl3".
Is there any other method to do this stuff?

In lecture examples i noticed putting it up together in the vertex shader but it was just for a simple 2d plane, not a 3d cube

```
tex_coords = vec2(vPosition.x+0.5,vPosition.z+0.5);
```

and later passed to fragment shader to create the texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But reviewing the slides i noticed this method is supposed to be "pre opengl3".

I think your slides refer to the old immediate mode. In immediate mode each vertex and its attributes are sent to OpenGL by calling functions that immediately draw them.

In your code however you're initializing a buffer with vertex data. This buffer *may* then passed as a whole to OpenGL and drawn as a batch by only a single OpenGL call. I wrote "*may*" because there's not a single OpenGL call in your question.

Comment: i pass vertices, coords and texture mapping as
    // set up vertex buffer objects
        final GLSLAttrib vertices = new GLSLAttrib(pointsBuf, "vPosition", 4);
        final GLSLAttrib colors = new GLSLAttrib(colorsBuf, "vColor", 4);
        final GLSLAttrib tex_coord = new GLSLAttrib(texcoord, "vCoord", 2);

and use with fragColor to create the cube

Comment: @mjanisz1: Whatever `GLSLAttrib` is, it's not part of OpenGL itself. It's part of a 3d party library for sure. And by the very naming of it "GLSLAttrib" I'd bet, that this thing builds a Vertex Array or even a Vertex Buffer Object. It's a bit strange to do it this way, especially because this kind of scaffolding obscures OpenGL and classes and OOP don't map very well to OpenGL.

Comment: yes unfortunatelly we have to use a library provided by our teacher. It is more less the same like in "INTERACTIVE COMPUTER GRAPHICS
A TOP-DOWN APPROACH WITH SHADER-BASED OPENGL" but for java.  Still having hope this is the proper approach to pass it to shaders. Or maybe there is a way to calculate the mapping from vertices passed as that "vertex buffer object" in the shader?

Comment: @mjanisz1: As long as you use a vertex buffer object you're fine. This is indeed the way to go.